# Launch different Powershell console from a console?

Tags: powershell

If I'm working within a single powershell console, and say I want to spawn another powershell console window.

Is there a way to do this?

If you type "powershell" at the prompt - it doesn't launch a new window, just starts a new powershell instance within the current console window.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Start-Process powershell
```

Comment: both works. but this 1 is easier to type/remember.

Comment: That'll do... Now what causes the background on the original console to be blue - but the "start-process powershell" console has a black background? (It's nice to have the differences)

Comment: Yeap, insert mode is disabled too.  Pretty weird!

Comment: The console background color is tied to the shortut that started the process. Since you're using Start-Process you launch the actual executable instead of the shortcut you don't get the background color or the other settings that are set via the shortcut. No good idea how to circumvent that.

Answer (score 4):

Quick Google search would have helped:

```
Invoke-item "$pshome\powershell.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

For admin console:

```
start-process powershell -verb runAs
```

Comment: Can you explain how this adds to or improves the accepted answer?

Comment: @Dave M - Can you explain how its different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @ StingyJack  Not sure what you are asking from me.  I asked if jakobii  could add detail to answer to explain why it adds to or improved accepted answer.